# permissions in applet Exception

Tags: java, permissions, applet

I have an applet which read a file on the client.

```
public class MyApplet extends Applet {
     public static void main(String[] args){
          JFrame frame = new JFrame();
          MyApplet inst = new MyApplet();
          frame.getContentPane().add(inst);
          ((JComponent)frame.getContentPane()).setPreferredSize(inst.getSize());
          frame.pack();
          frame.setVisible(true);
     }
     public MyApplet(){
          initGUI();
     }
     public String readFile() { 
          String thisLine, ret = ""; 
          String fn="c:\\1\\a.txt";
          try { 
            FileInputStream fin =  new FileInputStream(fn); 
            BufferedReader myInput = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(fin));
            while ((thisLine = myInput.readLine()) != null) {  
                ret += thisLine + "\n";
            } 
          } catch (Exception e) {
            ret = e.toString();
          } 
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Exception I'm getting

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "c:\1\a.txt" "read")
```

please help me
i signed applet

Answer (score 0):

Official Java docummentation from Oracle includes information about it.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/wstep2.html

Note that applets are considered not-too-secure in general, and therefore many problems (not only with permission management, but also with some browsers etc.) may appear, especially when trying to access files.